# How to catch twig errors and display custom 500 error page?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a patch to add some custom handling of 500 errors that run through the code in errors.inc, so that it returns a themed page in those cases.

This works well in certain conditions, but I have an error that occurred with a misnamed twig template, so I got

```
Twig_Error_Loader: Template "@mytheme/search-result/search-result--event.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "@mytheme/search-result/search-result--event.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.) in "themes/custom/mytheme/templates/node/node--admissions-event--search-result.html.twig" at line 1. in Twig_Loader_Chain->getCacheKey() (line 129 of /var/www/mytheme-qa/site/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php).
```

After some digging I see that this error is generated here:
/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/Loader/ThemeRegistryLoader.php

```
if ($throw) {
  throw new \Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Unable to find template "%s" in the Drupal theme registry.', $name));
}
```

The problem is this type of error isn't handled by Drupal.  It's a Twig engine error.  So an exception subscriber doesn't catch this.

Any suggestions on how to return a themed 500 page in fatal error cases like this at the theme layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked, there is no special handling of Twig exceptions in core, so they end up in `FinalExceptionSubscriber`. You can add a custom exception subscriber catching `Twig_Error_Loader` or `Twig_Error_Syntax` and return a themed response (though you might need to theme this yourself when the theme layer is broken because of the Twig error).

`error.inc` has nothing to do with this as long as there is no fatal error not catchable by Symfony (but this would be a failure of the Twig layer, which normally protects you from low level errors)

Comment: Great this works! I still need my patch to errors.inc though, as uncaught fatal errors end up there, but this is working much better than what I previously had, because it's catching additional errors, such as twig errors.